# How to set HTTP header img-type jpeg/png in AJAX when updating captcha?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Use jquery + php. Doing custom AJAX captcha. i.e user clicks on image, it automatically updates.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.post('/captcha.php', {}, function(resp){

        $("div").html(resp);

    });

});

</script>

<div></div>
```

in PHP header already sent, so if it includes into `<img src="/captcha.php" />` it prints captcha in jpeg. The problem seem to be is header that need to be sent. So, how can i do this? The header is sent in PHP. It doesnt work in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change an image in an HTML document, then change the src attribute of the image (or replace the image element with a new one). Don't use XMLHttpRequest at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in Your captcha.php file:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: I did this, it works fine if it's not AJAX. I'm looking for solve to make this ajaxed

Comment: So change only image address with jQuery. $("#imgElementId").attr("src",newAddress);

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the source **from a different script** then you can simply send the `src` of the file through a string value. In that way your `captcha.php` code becomes something like this

```
 $source="/path/to/the/file.jpg";
 header("Content-type:text/plain");
 print $source;
```

When you receive it you can do the following to change the source

```
$("#changeCaptchaButton").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "captcha.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("changing source of image");
        var source=data;
        $("#captchaImg").attr("src", source); 

      }
   });
});
```

If you are doing the change in the **current script** then don't use the ajax but use the latter jQuery method